# Using filecontents inside of xparse

Tags: xparse, filecontents

I'm trying to reproduce this using `xparse`:

```
\begin{filecontents}{sections/autogen/somefile.tex} % Line to auto-produce
    \begin{myotherenvironment}
    Do lots of stuff
    \end{myotherenvironment}
\end{filecontents}                                  % Line to auto-produce
\input{sections/autogen/somefile.tex}               % Line to auto-produce
```

The above works fine. I've tried this using both `NewDocumentCommand` and `NewDocumentEnvironment`, and using both `begin`/`end` and `csname`/`endcsname`. I'm showing attempting to include the `#2` manually, previously I was just attempting to use `NewDocumentEnvironment` with one required parameter

```
\NewDocumentCommand \writefile { m m } {%
  \typeout{Writing file sections/autogen/#1.tex}%
  \csname filecontents*\endcsname{sections/traces/autogen/#1.tex}%
  %\begin{filecontents}{sections/traces/autogen/#1.tex}
  #2
  %\end{filecontents}}%
  \csname endfilecontents*\endcsname%
}%
```

It seems that the file is being generated, but when using `NewDocumentEnvironment` `\end{writefile}` is being inserted into the file generated by `filecontents`. When using `NewDocumentCommand` there seem to be a multitude of problems.

An example output file would contain this:

```
  \captionsetup[table]{name=Listing}
  \table[H] \footnotesize
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
    \tabu to \textwidth {|r@{ }l|l|X|} %{|@{ }r@{:}l|l|X[l]|}
    \rowfont{\bfseries} & LPS & MTH & SC \\
    \lcell 12 & \lpscell #3 & \mthcell #4 & \sccell {\lstinline[style=jt]{foo}}
    \lcell 12 & \lpscell #3 & \mthcell #4 & \sccell {\lstinline[style=jt]{foo}}
    \lcell 12 & \lpscell #3 & \mthcell #4 & \sccell {\lstinline[style=jt]{foo}}
    \endtabu
  \endtable
  \captionsetup[table]{name=Table}
```

Comment: You can't use `filecontents` or `filecontents*` in the argument to another command because they are quite similar to `verbatim`. Can you add a short example of a typical file you'd like to write out?

Comment: Sure, I've added an example, perhaps there's a fix somewhere. This is reduced from my real code - In general I need to maintain the tabular format with my custom formatting for each cell, and the table comes from a NewDocumentEnvironment while each line comes from a NewDocumentCommand.

Comment: I can't see where a command form is better than the environment form. If it's just for adding a default path in front of the file name, then it shouldn't be difficult to adapt `filecontents`; with `fancyrb` there is already a generic facility.

Comment: Yea, the only point here is to allow me to use filecontents so I can doubly-include some of my complex tables, but to place all of the auto-generated files in a nice folder(and perhaps steal the name from some parameters that I'm already passing such as label). I don't care if the new item is an environment/command, but I can't get either to work. I'll take a look at fancyrb - I'm not understanding now how it can help me but I know nothing about it so that's expected ;-)

Comment: Do you really need to write out the tables or are you just wanting to typeset them again in the same document?

Comment: The latter - I want to repeat the tables at a later point. I'm writing them so later I can selectively call `\input`, is there another way to re-print?!

Comment: You can define a macro containing the table code and use the macro.

Comment: Ouch. That's true, but I'm talking 75+ tables currently so I was really hoping to do something more than manually wrapping them all in a macro. It sounds like we've beat this question to death though and there's just not a super easy solution. Thanks for all the help, and I'll still take a look at fancyrb when I get a chance, perhaps that will help out in some way

Comment: Hmm; there's the problem of `\lstinline` so the macro approach isn't really good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any approach with macros will fail because you want to preserve the contents and also use `\lstinline`.

You can exploit `VerbatimOut` from `fancyvrb`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb,xparse}
\usepackage{caption,tabu,listings}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{doubletable}{m}
 {\captionsetup[table]{name=Listing}%
  \table[htp]
  \VerbatimOut{sections/autogen/#1}}
 {\endVerbatimOut
  \input{sections/autogen/#1}
  \label{repeattable@#1}
  \endtable}

\NewDocumentCommand{\repeattable}{m}{%
  \begingroup\captionsetup[table]{name=Listing,list=no}
  \begin{table}[!htp]
  \renewcommand{\thetable}{\ref{repeattable@#1}}
  \input{sections/autogen/#1}
  \end{table}
  \endgroup
}


\begin{document}

\begin{doubletable}{1}
\footnotesize
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {|r@{ }l|l|X|} %{|@{ }r@{:}l|l|X[l]|}
  \rowfont{\bfseries} & LPS & MTH & SC \\
  x & y & z & \lstinline{foo}
\end{tabu}
\caption{X}
\end{doubletable}

Repeat it

\repeattable{1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: oh...wow..this works! I want to create a second account just to vote you twice! Seriously thank you for sticking with me through this!!